# Why doesn't wp_delete_post allow trashing for custom types?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

When you're trying to `wp_delete_post` a custom post type, it deletes it fully instead of moving it to trash as it is the normal behavior.

This happens because "force delete" is, by default false and it will only trash the post if it's of post / page type:

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9/src/wp-includes/post.php#L2467

Why is this happening and what are the dangers of re-writing this to handle every post type?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [wp_trash_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trash_post)?

This seems like the perfect fit for your purpose.  It will only permanently delete posts if you have your trash disabled, or added `define('EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS', 0);` to your wp-config.php file.

Comment: I understand that but my question was why it is architectured this way. Usually, when micro-decisions like these are made, their implications are bigger.